# How to use Lambda expression to re-write this calculated property?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I am studying C# .net now. I was asked to change this calculated property to lambda expression. I am stuck for quite a while here, please help.

```
public class ClientList : BindingList<Client>
    {
        public decimal TotalSales
        {
            get
            {
                decimal totalSales = 0.00m;
                for (int i = 0; i < this.Count(); i++)
                {
                    totalSales += this[i].Sales;
                }
                return totalSales;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you're looking for is the fold of a list-like element aka aggregation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ is your friend here. Using the Sum() function, you can apply a projection across all the elements in 'this' BindingList:

```
return this.Sum(i => i.Sales);
```

which means - check every item in the list of 'this', and 'sum' the Sales property. You may have to 'using System.Linq;'. This is assuming Sales is a decimal property already.

I'd read up more on Linq if I were you - some very neat transformations you can apply to achieve a lot with a little code - try 'Select' and 'Where' to begin with.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is just what I need.

Comment: Think of LINQ functions as operations that run on 'lists of things', rather than on things themselves. You can chain them together too.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
decimal totalSales = 0.00m;
this.ForEach(x => totalSales += x.Sales);
```

But there is another, more LINQish way. Do you want to do it yourself?

Comment: I think if they wanted to do it themselves, they already would have.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior And then they come for interview and fail

Comment: Well, yeah, if you're opposed to answering the question, by all means don't answer it. I don't see this answer as particularly useful, though.